# How to change a function code during the execution in java

Tags: java, function, artificial-intelligence, genetic-programming

I'm trying to make some kind of AI that will have acess to his own code and can modify it during the execution to be able to evolve

for example, during the runtime I want it to be able to change it's code from :

```
if (a>1){doSomething();}
```

to :

```
if (a>1){doSomethingElse();}
```

It is possible to do such a thing ?

If it is not possible, is it possible instead of writting it in a function, to have a String containing the algorithm like this :

```
String code = "if (a>1){doSomethingElse();}";
```

and running the string as code like that :

```
run(code);
```

And again, if that's not possible in java, is there a programming language where it can be possible ?

Comment: For the first case, you need to share more details to be able to tell you. You can definitely design your code to change the behaviour depending on data collected, but your example is too generic. About the second question yes, it is possible. In java you can write source code programmatically, compile it on the fly and execute it at your taste.

Comment: You can check ClassLoader and it's hard to give an exact answer

Comment: Let's focus on the second part. I'm not sure if it was clear that I want to run a code that will be able to modify some variables of my current program. If we were talking of the same thing, I would be happy to see a tutorial about writing source code programmatically

Comment: thanks, I will try to check ClassLoader

Comment: Lookup BeanShell. It allows scripting using Java.  https://beanshell.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can change class files and their code at runtime using [BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/).